# Rest API return response XML format, but same XML not get in result by using httpclient

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-web-api

I have created web API which return XML format response, like below:

```xml
<TXLife xmlns="http://ACORD.org/Standards/Life/2">
    <TXLifeResponse>
      <TransRefGUID>61ec7f39-5744-410e-b601-dcd89d8d6f27</TransRefGUID>
      <TransType tc="510">Form Instance Update</TransType>
      <TransSubType tc="1022500310">Annuity Application for Mani ManiM</TransSubType>
      <TransExeDate>2016-08-25-04:00</TransExeDate>
      <TransExeTime>16:36:41.157-04:00</TransExeTime>
      <TransMode tc="2">Original</TransMode>
      <NoResponseOK tc="0"/>
      <TransResult>
         <ResultCode tc="3">Received Pending</ResultCode>
      </TransResult>
   </TXLifeResponse>
</TXLife>
```

But when call API using httpclient, I received response but response data is not same as above instead I got decode of special character.

```
<string xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">&lt;? 
xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?&gt;
&lt;TXLife xmlns:acord="http://ACORD.org/Standards/Life/2"&gt;
&lt;TXLifeResponse&gt;
&lt;TransRefGUID&gt;dd8973e3-ac03-4690-908b- 
65da3d6a770f&lt;/TransRefGUID&gt;
&lt;TransType tc="510"&gt;Form Instance Update&lt;/TransType&gt;
&lt;TransSubType tc="1022500310"&gt;
      Annuity Application for  SUZANNE M PERSON&lt;/TransSubType&gt;
&lt;TransExeDate&gt;2020-08-17&lt;/TransExeDate&gt;
&lt;TransExeTime&gt;15:28:24Z&lt;/TransExeTime&gt;
&lt;TransMode tc="2"&gt;Original&lt;/TransMode&gt;
&lt;NoResponseOK tc="0" /&gt;
&lt;TransResult&gt;
  &lt;ResultCode tc="3"&gt;Received Pendinge&lt;/ResultCode&gt;
&lt;/TransResult&gt;
&lt;/TXLifeResponse&gt;
&lt;/TXLife&gt;</string>
```

I am using below code to call API:

```
string response = string.Empty;
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    client.BaseAddress = parameters.DestinationUri;
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/xml"));             

    var responseTask = client.PostAsXmlAsync(parameters.DestinationUri, request);
    responseTask.Wait();

    var result = responseTask.Result;

    if (result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        response = result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;                    
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Resolved. I fixed by just in API response. I return HttpResponseMessage instead of return string object. Changes in API like below

```
string response = "response string info";

        return new HttpResponseMessage()
        {
            Content = new StringContent(response, Encoding.UTF8, "application/xml")
        };
```